# Devise & Bootstrap checkbox in Ruby on Rails: how to fix automatic setting of margin-left:-20px?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm working on stylizing the Devise sign-in form (app/devise/sessions/new.html.erb) with Bootstrap (using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0), and have set the checkbox for "Remember Me" as such:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But for whatever reason, I think Bootstrap keeps automatically setting it so the checkbox-inline has a margin-left of -20px, because it shows this when I examine the element using Google Chrome's developer tools. In the browser I can change this setting to 0px and it fixes the problem, but I have no idea how to actually do this in my Rails application with either Bootstrap's CSS.SCSS customization file or any other method.

Does anyone know a possible fix for this? Thank you to all in advance.

Comment: Fixed the problem today, thanks for the answer Damein_Hogan. What I ended up doing is placing input#user_remember_me { margin-left: 0px; } inside of bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an override css file you can override the class within there. Display: inline; should fix it. I highly recommend using Chrome Dev tools to play around and then paste the css into your overrides file.

My typical overrides file lives in assets/stylesheets and is called framework_and_overrides.css.scss